# AWX в minikube при выполнении playbook из под runner ошибка git

Tags: git, ansible, awx

minikube v1.23.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Kubernetes v1.22.1 on Docker 20.10.8

AWX 19.5.0

Кусок кода playbook на котором получаю ошибку:

```
- name: Get running-config and save it
  ios_config:
   backup: yes
   backup_options:
     filename: "{{ ansible_net_hostname }}_{{ ansible_host }}_at_{{ time.stdout }}.cfg"
     dir_path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../cisco/backup/{{ ansible_net_hostname }}/{{ date.stdout }}"

- name: Tasks git sync
  shell: |
    git add .
    git commit -m "Device {{ inventory_hostname }} Backup on {{date.stdout}} "
    git push ansible-for-cisco master
  args:
    chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/.."
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: yes
```

При выполнении через ansible-playbook - всё проходит успешно.

При выполнении этого же playbook через AWX (из под runner) получаю ошибку из-за отсутсвтия корретных данных git:

На **git commit...**

```
 "*** Please tell me who you are.",
    "",
    "Run",
    "",
    "  git config --global user.email \"you@example.com\"",
    "  git config --global user.name \"Your Name\"",
    "",
    "to set your account's default identity.",
    "Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.",
    "",
    "fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'runner@automation-job-298-rh9m2.(none)')"
```

На **git push...**

```
"error: src refspec master does not match any",
"error: failed to push some refs to 'ansible-for-cisco'"
```

Если посмотреть подробности по заданию AWX видим вот такое содержимое:

playbook_dir - **/runner/project/playbooks/**

whoami - **runner**

содержимое .git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote &quot;origin&quot;]
    url = file:///var/lib/awx/projects/_8__bitbucket_cisco_sync
    fetch = +refs/heads/awx_internal/575d12ae-9509-4736-ad6d-fde3dbe8c5bb:refs/remotes/origin/awx_internal/575d12ae-9509-4736-ad6d-fde3dbe8c5bb
[branch &quot;awx_internal/575d12ae-9509-4736-ad6d-fde3dbe8c5bb&quot;]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/awx_internal/575d12ae-9509-4736-ad6d-fde3dbe8c5bb
```

содержимое **git remote -v**:

```
origin  file:///var/lib/awx/projects/_8__bitbucket_cisco_sync (fetch)
origin  file:///var/lib/awx/projects/_8__bitbucket_cisco_sync (push)
```

**Вопрос:** как заставить задания отрабатывать корректно?

Пробовал убирать *delegate_to*, вместо *shell* использовать *command*, пробовал модуль *git_acp* - в консоли работает, в AWX нет.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а почему не используется стандартный модуль для работы с git? Я в таске ничего хитровытянутого не увидел.

Comment: @donRumata может я где-то упустил, но не нашел как сделать push стандартным  модулем для работы с git. Может есть пример? В документации только checkout и pull.

Comment: А, фига, оказывается нет пуша! Фига! Я не знал. Сорян.

Comment: Может тебе в модуле `shell` прохардкорить, чтобы запускался именно баш, а не какой-нить ash или чё там есть в системе?